# Role Inheritance in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, inheritance, roles, sql-server-2017

I am fairly new to SQL.
I am trying to set up Roles for a function library I am making.

In my mind, inheritance from one role to a higher role just makes sense.
My thought (of course it fails due to the Inherit attribute):

```
USE SomeDb
go
create or alter function dbo.basicfunc()  returns int as begin return 0 end
go
create or alter function dbo.mediumfunc() returns int as begin return 1 end
go
create or alter function dbo.adminfunc()  returns int as begin return 2 end
go

create role db_role_basic
    grant execute on dbo.basicfunc to db_role_basic

create role db_role_medium    --INHERIT from db_role_basic
    ALTER ROLE db_role_medium add member db_role_basic
    grant execute on dbo.mediumfunc to db_role_medium

create role db_role_admin     --INHERIT from db_role_medium
    ALTER ROLE db_role_admin add member db_role_medium
    grant execute on dbo.adminfunc to db_role_admin

create login AdminLogin with password = 'P$1p11'
create user  AdminUser  for login AdminLogin
alter role db_role_admin add member AdminUser

SETUSER 'AdminUser'

select dbo.adminfunc()
select dbo.basicfunc()
```

So in the end, the Admin role would have all the permissions of the lower roles.

And if I change permissions to a lower role, it trickles up the chain...    And I am not duplicating the instructions for each role.

As it is here, I get the error:

```
Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Line 391
The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'BasicFunc', database 'mds test db', schema 'dbo'.
```

Answer (score 1):

This

```
create role db_role_basic
    grant execute on dbo.basicfunc to db_role_basic

create role db_role_medium    --INHERIT from db_role_basic
    ALTER ROLE db_role_medium add member db_role_basic
    grant execute on dbo.mediumfunc to db_role_medium

create role db_role_admin     --INHERIT from db_role_medium
    ALTER ROLE db_role_admin add member db_role_medium
    grant execute on dbo.adminfunc to db_role_admin
```

is no kind of "inheritence"  You've added all the members of `db_role_basic` to `db_role_medium`, which is the opposite of what you want.  Insetad add `db_role_admin` to `db_role_medium` and `db_role_medium` to `db_role_basic`.  eg

```
create role db_role_basic
create role db_role_medium    
create role db_role_admin   
go

ALTER ROLE db_role_basic add member db_role_medium
ALTER ROLE db_role_medium add member db_role_admin


grant execute on dbo.basicfunc to db_role_basic
grant execute on dbo.mediumfunc to db_role_medium
grant execute on dbo.adminfunc to db_role_admin
```

Comment: Many Thanks David !

To put it into English - this is giving the 'Higher' role access to the options in the 'Lower' role --  'you can see what I see'  :-)